# "do theorizing" or "go theorizing"

Tags: grammar

Is Following sentence grammatically correct,

> is it possible to **do** theorizing without storymaking?

or this one,

> is it possible to **go** theorizing without storymaking?

Note: I want to make a sentence that express "making a theory" is began from "making a story", thanks.

Comment: Neither of these is correct. Can you please expand what it is you're asking about?  Or consider asking on English Language Learners SE

Comment: @DavidM I want to make a sentence that express "making a theory" is began from "making a story"

Comment: I've flagged for a moderator to do so.

Comment: "Is it possible to *theorise*..." (or *theorize* in American English)

Comment: thank you about your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those sentences are theoretically grammatical (in terms of syntax), with one caveat: *storymaking* isn't a word that's commonly defined in most dictionaries. Instead, it would be [*storytelling*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/storytelling) or, depending on your meaning, *making up stories*.

Also, that word aside, the sentence as a whole isn't very idiomatic. Neither *do theorizing* nor *go theorizing* sounds natural.

In short, it would typically be expressed in different ways:

> Is it possible to **theorize** without *storytelling*?
>   Is it possible to **theorize** without *making up stories*?

Or perhaps even better, stylistically:

> Is it possible to **engage in theory** without *resorting to fiction*?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.